# Setting Image from SDWebImage on UITableView Reload

Tags: swift, uitableview, sdwebimage, reloaddata

I have a list of cells within a UITableView.  The images are being downloaded by the following method inside the cell

```
self.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: profileURL), completed: { (image, error, cache, url) in
                            if image != nil {
                                self.profileImage.image = image
                            } else {
                                print("didn't load image")
                            }
                        })
```

However, upon reloading and resorting the UITableView the previous image for that index is loaded for a brief moment and then after that the updated image for that index appears.

Now my theory is the following happens (correct me if I'm wrong)...

1. The image is downloaded as soon as the URL is retrieved.
2. That image is cached with SDWebImage.
3. TableView reloads and data in cells change.
4. SDWebImage uses the cached image for that indexPath instead of the cell. (Problem here)
5. SDWebImage downloads the URL again for that cell and refreshes the image.

If this is correct what I need is to do the following...

1. Download image as soon as the URL is retrieved.
2. Cache the image with SDWebImage.
3. TableView reloads and data in cells change.
4. Use the cached image for that cell.

Am I using the wrong method for setting the self.profileImage?

As always any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1.Download image as soon as the URL is retrieved.*
*2.Cache the image with SDWebImage.*

you use this code

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://test.com/upload/image.jpg")!

self.imageD.sd_setImage(with: url as URL!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default_logo"), options: .transformAnimatedImage, progress: nil, completed: nil)
```

this **default_logo** put inside **Assets.xcassets**

*3.TableView reloads and data in cells change.*

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: this removes the downloaded images and replaces them with the placeholder image.  HOWEVER, when UITableView is reloaded this works perfectly.  Do you know how I would get them to show when viewDidLoad?

Comment: nevermind just stuck self.profileImage.image = image in the completion block seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your cells using UITableViewCell, than you can override method prepareForReuse() for clearing old images, for example:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    profileImage.image = nil
}
```

By this way old cached images won't be appear.